# Filter rows based on dynamically selecting columns by their name

Tags: sqlite

I have a [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/?hl=es#calendartxt) database. I want to query the `calendar` table.

That table has the following columns:

```
service_id | monday | tuesday | wednesday | thursday | friday | saturday | sunday | start_date | end_date

1          | 0      | 0       | 1         | 0        | 1      | 0        | 0      | 20190317   | 20200101
...
...
...
```

I know how to get the `service_id`s between the start and the end date, but I'm not sure how to filter the rows based on if they are enabled (`1`) or disabled (`0`) in the current day when the query happens.

The expected result would be all rows who's `start_date <= now >= end_date` and that are enabled for the current day.

Example: If I ran the query today (thursday), it won't return the row that I provided in my example. But if I run the query tomorrow (friday), it will return the row in my example.

Is this possible? (I'm using SQLite)

Comment: You need to provide more details of your requirement, with sample data and expected results.

Comment: @forpas I believe the question is very clear, but ok, I'll update it.

Comment: If feasible, I'd change the table definition to something like `CREATE TABLE calendar(start_date, end_date, service_id INTEGER, day_of_week)`. Your row would take up two in this table, but then you can use `SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE service_id = 1 AND day_of_week = 'thursday'` etc. Use numbers instead of strings for the weekday, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply add condition for days:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE service_id = ?
  AND ? BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
  AND (CASE 
      WHEN  strftime('%w', ?) = 1 AND monday = 1  THEN 1
      WHEN  strftime('%w', ?) = 2 AND tuesday = 1 THEN 1
      ...
      END) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `strftime('%w', 'now')` you get a number for today's week day (0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, ...).
So you can use a CASE statement like this:

```
select * from tablename
where 1 = case strftime('%w', 'now')
  when 0 then sunday 
  when 1 then monday 
  when 2 then tuesday 
  when 3 then wednesday 
  when 4 then thursday 
  when 5 then friday 
  when 6 then saturday
end
```

You can add additional conditions for start_date and end_date.